# jscrollPane destroy(); and modernizr

Tags: jscrollpane, modernizr

Currently trying to remove jScrollPane when the width is a certain size. It appears to be working, I can trigger alert with

```
   if (Modernizr.mq("screen and (max-width:715px)")) {
         alert('hello world');          
   }
```

And I can remove jScrollPane with click functionality

```
$('.st-accordion a').click(function() {
        var element = $('.hs-content').jScrollPane({});
        var api = element.data('jsp');
        api.destroy();
});
```

But for whatever reason I can't trigger destroy(); with the modernizr conditional

```
            if (Modernizr.mq("screen and (max-width:715px)")) {
                    var element = $('.hs-content').jScrollPane({});
                    var api = element.data('jsp');
                    api.destroy();
            }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got it by enclosing it all in the same function. A moment of clarity.

```
            //Scrollpane
            $(function()
                {
                    $('.hs-content').jScrollPane({  autoReinitialise: true, hideFocus: true });
                    $('.hs-menu nav').jScrollPane({  autoReinitialise: true, hideFocus: true });
                    if (Modernizr.mq("screen and (max-width:715px)")) {
                    var element = $('.hs-content').jScrollPane({});
                    var api = element.data('jsp');
                    api.destroy();
                    }
             });
```